# Mp Android Chart. I am not able to show bar labels in horizontal bar label

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am prety new in Mp Android Chart and android . I am wondering to draw the Horizontal BarChart Labels but i am not able to do. I want to write the labels that i put in my data entrys. I want to write the labels like the once in the graph that is in the link(Jun,May,Apr)

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2ec281e0ac3013076bff1c3ac00d8d6de372d7a4/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d5043686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f686f72697a6f6e74616c5f62617263686172742e706e67

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
System.out.println("Message");
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
mChart = (HorizontalBarChart) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
// mChart.setHighlightEnabled(false);
drawUI();

XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xl.setDrawAxisLine(false);
xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
xl.setDrawLabels(true);

    YAxis yl = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    yl.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
    yl.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    yl.setDrawGridLines(false);
    yl.setDrawLabels(True);

YAxis yr = mChart.getAxisRight();
yr.setDrawAxisLine(false);
yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
yr.setDrawLabels(false);
// yr.setInverted(true);

    mChart.setFitBars(false);
    mChart.animateY(2500);
    return myFragmentView;   

}

public void drawUI()
{
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    Team LocalTeam = activity.GetTeam(1);

    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(1 *2f, LocalTeam.getRedCard(),"Rojas"));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(2 *2f, LocalTeam.getYellowCard(),"Amarillas"));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(3 *2f, LocalTeam.getOffSide(),"Off Side"));
```

Incorrecto"));
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(10 *2f, LocalTeam.getPass(),"pases"));

```
    BarDataSet set1 ;

    set1= new BarDataSet(yVals1,"Local");
    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);    

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);    

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    mChart.invalidate();


}
}`
```

Comment: There's a little bit too much code here, making your question harder to read and answer. Could you create a [mcve]?

Comment: now its ok ? i have no idea how to add the labels

Answer (score 0):

```
yVals.add(new BarEntry(LocalTeam.getRedCard(),"Rojas"),1 *2f);
```